# Freeform Composer General Errors Not Showing on MSM

Tags: solspace-freeform

We have a website that is powered by MSM.

On the main website forms work fine and the form errors show.

On the sub-sites, the forms send but they don't show the general errors.

The code in question is:-

```
        {exp:freeform:composer form_name="{embed:form}" admin_notify="{embed:email}|info@redcarrot.co.uk" admin_notification_template="{embed:template}" inline_error_return="{embed:page}/#freeform" return="{embed:page}/thanks#freeform" inline_errors="yes"}
    {if freeform:general_errors}
        <h3>There were some error(s) with your submission:</h3>
        <ul>
            {freeform:general_errors}
                <li>{if "{freeform:error_message}"=="captcha_required"}Please type the two words at the bottom of the form{if:else}{freeform:error_message}{/if}</li>
            {/freeform:general_errors}
        </ul>
    {/if}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed.

Freeform stores inline errors in a "Flash" cookie. Because we had the cookie consent module enabled (with the intention to not set any cookies to users) it couldn't set them.

The reason it appeared to work on the main website was because we were logged into CP and thus had accepted cookies. D'oh!